# why the button is not display and text view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I am new to android development . I've made a simple demo of login screen. I used Xml to do this and have checked my output on landscape and portrait mode. It looks fine in portrait mode, but on landscape my **login** button is not visible and I am not able to scroll my view. I used **dp** in my xml file and I think it is due to dp that I have this problem.

Here are my screen shots to show what is displayed.[image]

This is portrait mode which is looking fine ..

[image]

When I rotate my device it moves to landscape, but it is not showing button and below text view? Can I add **scroll view ?** or **can I add in % percentage instead of dp**?

Here is my code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#223399"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Login here"
        android:gravity="center"
        />


    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/loginClick"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="New User?"
        android:textColor="#00eeff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/regiester_id"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

**java code**

```
   public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

How can I set the screen up so that it looks good in portrait as well as landscape mode?

**Update code**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#223399"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Login here"
        android:gravity="center"
        />


    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/loginClick"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="New User?"
        android:textColor="#00eeff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/regiester_id"
        />
    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use `android:layout_weight`. 
Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean

Comment: i know layout weight i thing in this it is not used

Comment: Scrollview must have a single child only not multiple child so use linearlayout inside of scroll view. Then use multiple child in that linear layout.

Answer (score 1):

I gave it a quick try using layout_weight. You can more fine tune it using different weights.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#223399"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Login here"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/loginClick"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="New User?"
        android:textColor="#00eeff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/regiester_id"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> when i rotate my device it move to landscape .it is not showing button
>   and below text view ? can I add scroll view ? or can I add in %
>   percentage instead of dp.

I would say use `ScrollView` for better screen adjustment, it will be helpful in smaller device screens too.

also you can make different types of layouts for every size of screens and for `landscape` and `portrait`.

please refer to developer's [site](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for types of screen layouts.

I hope you will get info for different types of screen size from there.

Comment: I understant that i need to add scroll view ..ok I will try and update you

Comment: I update code with scroll view it crash my application why /?

Comment: could you please tell me why it is crashing

Comment: can you show logcat? without logcat i can not say why it is crashing, also make scrollview as a parent view and put linearlayout inside of it.

Comment: @DeepakGoyal i did not ask the question. Please tell to who has asked question.

Comment: this answer is not for you. I an telling the @user944513 to update his code.

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView` must have only one child, try to change your code like that:

```
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#223399">

       <LinearLayout  
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Login here"
                android:gravity="center"
                />


            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                />
            <EditText
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Login"
                android:id="@+id/loginClick"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="New User?"
                android:textColor="#00eeff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/regiester_id"
                />

       </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Scroll View Must have one child. So update your code with below and seee its working or not.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#223399"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Login here"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:hint="Username" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:hint="Password" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/loginClick"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:text="Login" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/regiester_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="New User?"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#00eeff" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```